# Добавить картинку перед классом

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть плагин BeRocket через который на wp реализованы фильтры товаров. Сам по себе плагин не позволяет добавить картинку перед фильтром, по-этому пришел к тому, что нужно использовать хуки.
Есть фильтры - ul в котором обернуты li с классом bapf_1_26. Задача поставить перед каждым li картинку. В целом в инспекторе получилось заредачить li вставив просто картинку :

```
<li><input data-name="3D Printing" id="bapf_1_26" type="checkbox" value="26"><img src="https://soldered1.johnsdevserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/easyc.svg"><label for="bapf_1_26">3D Printing</label></li>
```

Но не пойму как добавить картинку в коде function.php хуком.

Comment: нашел документацию по плагину, там можно редачить и добавлять шаблоны - 
http://docs.berocket.com/plugin/woocommerce-ajax-products-filter#add-more-styles
но запутался еще больше, что куда менять и подставлять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации по ссылке есть ссылка на шаблоны всех стилей плагина. Скачиваем их и ищем checkbox.php. В нем после function template_full создаем цикл for

```php
function template_full($template, $terms, $berocket_query_var_title) {             
            $template = parent::template_full($template, $terms, $berocket_query_var_title);
            for($i=0; $i<count($template['template']['content']['filter']['content']['list']['content']); $i++) {
                $template['template']['content']['filter']['content']['list']['content']['element_'.$i]['content'];
                $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $terms[$i]->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
                $image_url    = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
                array_unshift($template['template']['content']['filter']['content']['list']['content']['element_'.$i]['content'],array(
                    'type'          => 'tag_open',
                    'tag'           => 'img',
                    'attributes'    => array(
                        'src'     => $image_url
                    ),
                ));
```

После этого добавится картинка